# Efficiency problem

Tags: java, algorithm, math

i am trying to make my algorithm more efficient but for some reason its not working correctly could someone tell me if my logic is correct. The general problem is that if u have a height of 'x', and you can jump 'u' distance but you fall 'd' distance if you havent cleared the height already. i have to calculate the number of jumps.

Initial code works correctly

```
while(x-u>0) {
    x=x-u+d;
    i++;
}
i++;
```

more efficient code (for some reason fails some cases, I don't know which cases though)

```
int k=u-d;
if(x-u<=0){
    i++;
} else {
    int z=x/k;
    if (x-((z-1)*k)-u <= 0) {
        i+=z;
    } else {
        i=i+z+1;
    }
}
```

let me try and clarify the problem you have a wall of height X, you can jump up distance U but every time you jump you also slip down distance D.
so lets say if u have a wall of height x=4, u=4, d=1. Then you would only have to jump once because the first time you jump you have cleared the wall, so you dont slip down at all. now lets say x=6, u=4,d=1. Then you would have to jump twice because the first time you would jump up to 4 but fall 1 so you are at 3 then the next jump you clear the wall.

Comment: No idea, based on what you've posted.  Can't tell what x, u, z, d, i, or k are.  A jaunt through a debugger should tell you.

Comment: whats k? and z? and can you explain d again? and why you need d?

Comment: Not sure I understand why you have the falling aspect of this, but in any case, it sounds like you should write this problem down algebraically, and solve it symbolically, then implement that as a piece of code.

Comment: `for some reason fails some cases, I don't know which cases though` How did you discover there were failures if you don't know when it fails? (might help to have that information)

Comment: the question is from a coding competition, they dont give all the test cases, but the loop passes all of them where as the non looped one doesnt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, let's see. The *last* jump comes from the height of `x - u` or higher. The rest you have to cover in `(u - d)`-size steps, the number of such steps is of course `(x - u)/(u - d)`.

After `i`-th step you are at height `i * (u - d) + u` (and falling down). So, in approx. `(x - u)/(u - d)` steps you are at height `x - u + u = x`. Recalling that the number of steps should be a whole number, we get the final result:

```
if (u >= x)
    return 1;
if (u <= d)
    throw "Impossible";
return ceil((x - u)/(u - d));
```

(`ceil` is a mathematical function returning the smallest integer not less than the given number.)